# C++ overflow detection for large numbers (unsigned long long)

Tags: c++, try-catch, overflow, unsigned-long-long-int

I am dealing with large integers (unsigned long long) and need to guard for overflow conditions. The code throws the exception regardless if there actually is one:

```
try
{
    unsigned long long y = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() - 2;
    unsigned long long z = 1;
    int size = - 1;
    if((y+z) ^ y < 0) //If y+z causes overflow its sign will be changed => y and (y+z) will have opposite signs
        throw std::overflow_error("overflow of y+z");
    //int* myarray= new int[size]; VS Debug Library catches it earlier than catch()
    printf("%d\n", y*(y+z));
}
catch(exception& e)
{
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Since it is of the largest data type(64 bits) already, there is no room to promote to anything larger.

New code:

```
try
{
    unsigned long long int y = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max() - 2;
    unsigned long long int z = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max() / 2;
    unsigned long long delta = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max() - y;
    int size = - 1;
    if(z > delta) //If y+z causes overflow its sign will be changed => y and (y+z) will have opposite signs
        throw std::overflow_error("overflow of y+z");
    //int* myarray= new int[size]; VS Debug Library catches it earlier than catch()
    printf("%d\n", (y+z));
}
catch(exception& e)
{
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Comment: related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`y < 0` will always be false, and anything xor 0 will always be that thing (Did you miss that `<` is evaluated at higher precedence than `^`?).

Therefore unless `x + y` mod `<the max value>` happens to equal 0, you will throw (and probably appears to always throw in practice unless you contrived specific inputs).

Perhaps what you meant to do was something like this: `if((std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() - y) < z) throw ...;`

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues. The main one is [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence): `<` is higher than `^`. This is a great reason to compile with all warnings enabled as both gcc and clang give me a warning about this expression and suggest parentheses!

Your expression, as evaluated by the compiler, is really:

```
if ( (y+z) ^ (y < 0) )
```

Since `y < 0` evaluates as `0`, that's just:

```
if (y+z)
```

which is obviously `true`. But even if you had the parentheses correct, as:

```
if (((y+z) ^ y) < 0) { ... }
```

That expression is trivially `false`. It will still have type `unsigned long long` which will never evaluate as `< 0`.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the code (see original post). If you know of a neat trick could please post: